# Use javax.servlet 2.5 plugin in Juno

Tags: jakarta-ee, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-juno, servlet-3.0, servlet-2.5

While developing plugins for Eclipse, I want to use the `javax.servlet` plugin that comes bundled with Java EE eclipse. I found that However, the version packaged with Juno comes with servlet 3.0 specs. Is there a way to install and use the plugin with Juno that provides servlet 2.5 API?